# Ethernet Loopback Test

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ethernet

I am trying to create a test to verify a PHY loopback is working correctly. Developing on linux in c. This is essentially what the test is currently doing:

1. Bring up the interface and make sure it has a valid IP address
2. Create two sockets in UDP mode (SOCK_DGRAM)
3. Bind both sockets to the specific interface being tested
4. Bind the incoming socket to a specific port
5. Write to the outgoing socket with sendto, specifying the port and IP address
6. Read from the incoming socket

The problem I'm having is, with or without loopback enabled, I am always reading the data back. The interface is not connected to a switch, so I wouldn't expect the data to come back over the physical cable. I suspect the stack is routing the data back before before it ever gets to the PHY. Is there some way to ensure packets are physically sent out an interface?

Comment: I suspect what I may need to do, is send a packet out with a destination different from the interface address. Then I would have to watch the interface for any incoming packet, even packets not intended for it. Sort of a raw 'sniff' mode.

Answer (score 1):

As you may have guessed, this is not a bug but a feature (and an essential one). However I doubt you will ever be able to test the PHY without a second receiver.

Case #1: The NIC sends the data to a hub (do these still exist?). The hub will just amplify the signal. Nobody will talk back to the NIC about the signal. The NIC has no interest in reading its own signal while sending it.

Case #2: The NIC sends the data to a switch. The switch will in its routing automatically never send the signal back to the source. It does not make sense to do it and would in some cases (e.g. broadcast packages) lead to serious trouble in the network.

Case #3: You have a complicated network setup where loops are possible. Either your network is f*cked up or you use techniques like Spanning Tree to explicitely prevent your signal to be ever routed back to you.

As you can see, the internal data routing is essential. You stand no chance to send something over one physical ethernet interface and receiving it at the same end.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to put one of the interfaces into the separate namespace.

Bash example (note, that all commands from other network namespace are prepended with `ip netns exec $NS`):

1. Prepare some variables:

   ```bash
   IF1=ens6f0
   IF2=enp4s0f1
   IP1=10.10.10.1
   IP2=10.10.10.2
   NMASK=24
   NS=mynamespace
   ```
2. Create namespace and put one of the interfaces there

   ```bash
   ip netns add $NS
   ip link set dev $IF1 netns $NS
   ip netns exec $NS ip link set dev lo up
   ip netns exec $NS ip link set dev $IF1 up
   ```
3. Setup interface addresses

   ```bash
   ip netns exec $NS ip address flush dev $IF1
   ip netns exec $NS ip address add dev $IF1 $IP1/$NMASK
   ip address flush dev $IF2
   ip address add dev $IF2 $IP2/$NMASK
   ```
4. Start UDP listener

   ```bash
   ncat -4lu $IP2 1234
   ```
5. Connect to listener

   ```bash
   ip netns exec $NS ncat -4u $IP2 1234
   ```

   At this point, you may send data to listener. If you disconnect cable between interfaces, data flow will stop.
6. Cleanup

   ```bash
   ip netns exec $NS ip link set dev $IF1 netns 1
   ip link set dev $IF1 up
   ip netns delete $NS
   ip address flush dev $IF1
   ip address flush dev $IF2
   ```